Where should I place email notifications - in Infrastructure Layer or Application layer?
I am learning the onion architecture and currently in the process of developing backend service, which follows this architecture. One of functionalities I want to include in my application is to send emails to certain users whenever they receive a new message.
Application layer should define business logic, validation logic, essentially use cases. Infrastructure layer provides implementation of repositories, essentially interaction with external systems. Email notifications fit the infrastructure layer description. So my guess is that I have to create EmailNotificationService inside of infrastructure layer, and then use this service inside of Presentation layer. In current application my presentation layer is defined by the REST api endpoints in .NET Core web application.
So for example inside of my Presentation layer I will do the following in one of my controllers:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendMessage(Message message)
{
    var result = await UserService.SendMessage(message);
    await EmailService.Send(message);
    return Results.Ok(result);
}

Does this approach follow the clean architecture? Or should I place email notifications in another layer (like Application layer, for example)


Infrastructure layer provides implementation of repositories

I would argue that your emphasis is a bit wrong here, I would put it on the implementation part.
You should define the EmailNotificationService as interface on the domain level (by the name it sounds specific enough to not contain application level logic so domain seems to be a better option here, possibly it would be a good idea to rename it to EmailMessageSender instead of service) and then implement it on the infrastructure one (and arguably use DI principle to provide the implementation to corresponding consumers)

I have to create EmailNotificationService inside of infrastructure layer, and then use this service inside of Presentation layer
So for example inside of my Presentation layer I will do the following in one of my controllers

Looks like you are creating a use-case in the presentation layer (a bit hard to tell without seeing actual implementations). What if UserService decides if push-notification should be send, not an email one, what if there should be send no message at all due to some business rule?

Agree with above, you should have a NotificationService, not an EmailService, and it should be called by the UserService.SendMessage(), which should have an implementation injected of an EmailMessageSender.
The UserService can decide how to send the message, hiding that implementation from the Presentation layer, and allowing it to be abstracted/stubbed for testing (testing email is notoriously problematic / expensive)
